# SetLayoutProperty is 'undefined' despite previous checks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, undefined, mapbox-gl-js

I have an issue in a mapboxgl js project. I am trying to display a heatmap and change it to a simple circle layer when the zoom is high enough.
Despite checks i get this : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getValue')`

Here is the piece of code where it is included

```
   useEffect(() => {
    if (props.map && props.map.getLayer('data')) {
      console.log(zoom)
        if (zoom > 15) {
          props.map.setLayoutProperty('data', 'type', 'circle');
        } else {
          props.map.setLayoutProperty('data', 'type', 'heatmap');
        }
      }
    }, [props.map, zoom]);
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

I tried to add specific checks to ensure the map is fully loaded and the layer exists but i still get this issue

Comment: I don't see `getValue` in this snippet

Comment: Hi! Yes from my understnding the getvalue is packaged in the heatmap layout property:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getValue')
    at heatmap.getLayoutProperty (style_layer.js:118:1)
    at Jt.setLayoutProperty (style.js:1084:1)
    at Map.setLayoutProperty (map.js:2591:1)
    at TrashLayer.js:50:1

Comment: There is usually a stack trace with the error that shows file name and line numbers

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't simply change the layer type from `circle` to `heatmap` and vice versa. The getValue() error occurs in the internal Mapbox implementation rather than in your code.

A more robust approach is to create two layers and define their min and max zoom to be adjacent (or a little overlapping).

This way you don't need any code for your desired functionality.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick answer. It's a shame this is not more explicit. I will try with two distinct layers!